# C++ access specifiers

Tags: c++, private, public, access-specifier

I just want to make sure I got the idea of public and private right.

Regarding the private access specifier, does it mean:

- *Only* accessed inside the class
- Cannot be accessed from the object of the class unless there are public class methods that can be used to access them (**Can other objects use those public functions?**)
- No other object can access them

And for public:

- Accessed from the object of the class
- Accessed from any other object

Is that right?

Comment: there's a third common level: `protected`. this works like private, with the exception that subclasses may also access protected methods/data. of course, a compiler will also check that your accesses conform to the interface. private locks subclasses out of the private interface of the base class.

Comment: I think you are mixing up concepts. What is "the object of the class"? In this context, a class and an object of the class are basically the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue of vocabulary to begin with.

In C++ (and most languages) a `class` is a `type`. You can think about it as a blueprint to actually build something.

- it describes the attributes that are held
- it describes the methods to operate on those attributes
- it describes the restrictions that apply: this is the "accessibility"

An `object` is produced by actually instantiating a class, that is, building what the blueprint described. It is more or a less a bundle of attributes. You can have several objects of the same class as you can have several houses from the same blueprint: note that their physical location is different for obvious reasons :)

Now, on to the accessibility. There are 3 typical levels of accessibility: `public`, `protected` and `private`.

- `public`, as expected, means that everyone is given access to either attributes or methods
- `protected` is somewhat less trivial. It means that only the object, or its children, may access the attributes (bad idea*) or methods. (Plus, in C++, `friend`s)
- `private` means that only the objects of that class (and not their children) may access the attributes or methods (Plus, in C++, `friend`s)

Note: whatever the level of accessibility, an object has **unrestricted** access to all the attributes and methods of any object of the same class.

(*) Even though it pops up now and there, it is generally a bad idea to use `protected` attributes. The point of encapsulation is to hide the details, not only for the sake of it, but because by precisely controlling who can access the data, we can ensure that the class maintains its *invariants* (simple example, an array where you would store the size separately, you need to ensure that the "size" really represents the number of items in the array, at all times). *Note: this restriction does not apply when you can **seal** a hierarchy, like in C# for example.*

Comment: Your wording makes `protected` sound more restrictive than `private` for the same class. Also, what are an object's children?

Comment: @juanchopanza: "children" is meant to be "super-objects" (in case of a derived instance accessing the attributes of its base object). If you have a better wording to propose, I am all for it.

Comment: Maybe s/object/type/ ?

Answer (score 4):

**private** : Only member functions and friends of class can access it.
**public**  : Can be accessed anywhere where the object has scope.

---

Answering the questions -

**private**:

1. Yes
2. Yes. (Can other objects use those public functions? With out having class relations, one object of class cannot communicate to the other's members. )
3. Friends has access to private members of a class. So, answer depends upon your class has friends or not.

**public**:

1. Yes
2. Depends whether the object has hierarchical relations to the member's class you are trying to access.

Comment: In OOP, a very important access specifier completely left out here is, of course, `protected`, which basically works like `private`, except that subclasses of the declaring class have access to those members as well.

Comment: @pdinklag: not very important really. Definitely a bad idea for attributes, near useless for functions, can be used with constructors/assignment/destructors in some scenarios.

Comment: @Matthieu, not near useless for functions. A set of pure virtual protected functions is often used to define an interface that derived classes should implement. Then the base class uses this interface to perform actual tasks. [QIODevice::readData()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html#readData) is a good example of that.

Comment: @Sergey: I don't mean that it cannot be used, but there is little distinction between `protected` and `public`, at best it's a documentation feature as far as I am concerned. Demo: `struct B: QIODevice { x readDataHack() { return readData(); } };`, now `readData` is, for all intents and purposes, `public`. Note that it doesn't apply to constructors/destructors and the like.

Comment: @Matthieu, well, I guess one can abuse anything, but it doesn't make it useless, because now you have to intentionally do something silly like that, while if it was public from the very beginning, it wouldn't prevent even accidental uses of it outside the class. Someone could just use readData() instead of the proper read() method. When readData() is protected, he'll see an error instead, read carefully the docs and use the correct method this time.

Comment: @Sergey: I agree, it's an annotation checked by the compiler rather than a "simple" comment. But `private` would be more useful here (for pure virtual at least). `protected` can be used when you provide an implementation, because this way, even overriden, one can call the initial implementation in the override.

Comment: @Matthieu, pure virtual functions can have implementation too. Not sure if it can be considered a good practice, though.

Comment: @Sergey: yes, I have used it a few times, when a meaningful default can be provided but you want the developer to make a conscious choice. In this case, obviously, `private` is no good.

Answer (score 2):

Private members can only be accessed by member functions and static functions of the same class and by friends of the class. It does not matter on which object that function is called. So the case

```
class Foo
{
  private:
    void bar() {}
  public:
    void baz(Foo& var)
    {
      var.bar();
    }
}
```

is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

That seems correct.  Data members and functions marked public can be accessed from anywhere by anyone.  Data members and functions marked private can only be accessed by the class and its friends.  However, a member function of a class can access data with any access specifier, so a public function can read and write private data members (this is used universally in OOP).

Answer (score 0):

In c++ data  and fn are encapsulated as 1 unit.
We begin a program  by writing 
 preprocessor directives
Then, class declaration
Followed by function(fn) declaration where we also specify the access modifier ( public, private or protected)

& finally the main () program.

If we declare a fn 
Private:the  data within an object of a class is  only accessed by fn defined within it- (the object which has the data and the private fn)

Public:the data can be accessed by any fn

Protected:similar to private however data can also be accessed by sub-classes that inherit the properties of another class.

Example if class A inherits from class B,  thenA is a subclass of B.

Comment: Hope u will find this useful.