# C++ Error in calling the function

Tags: c++

I have a function definition of the following form (within a large code):

```
class Abc{
 public:
 bool func(const std::string& text,::DE::d type,unsigned a,unsigned& b);
 };
```

Here DE is a class of the following form:

```
class DE
{
   public:
   enum d{U,L};

};
```

Now I am calling the function in the following form:

```
string s;
unsigned st=0;
int idj;
cout<<"\n Enter the value of string:";
cin>>s;
Abc abc;
abc.func(s,DE::U, 0,  idj); 
cout<<idj;
```

Upon the call of the function func in      `abc.func(s,DE::U, 0,  idj);` I am getting the below mentioned error. Can someone be kind enough to help find and rectify the error.

The error that I am getting is:

```
   error: no matching function for call to ‘Abc::func(std::string&, DE::U, unsigned int&, int&)’
```

Comment: did you forget to add the error?

Comment: I think the error is pretty much there

Comment: @user1355603, could you, in future, paste **all** of the errors, not single (and not *first*!) error? In many cases, first error gives clues for next of them; you should fix them top-to-bottom, not bottom-to-top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about [access specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919460/c-access-specifiers).

```
class Abc{
 bool func(const std::string& text,::DE::d type,unsigned a,unsigned& b);
};
```

`Abc::func()` is private, so cannot be called, or referenced, from outside. Same with enum in `DE`.

Plus, you cannot pass `int`, where reference to `unsigned int` is required.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, although the access specifiers are public

Comment: @user1355603, I added last line after posting this; you want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

`idj` is of type `int`; it should be `unsigned int` to be passed as parameter `b`.

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter type is a reference to `unsigned`. You are trying to pass a reference to `int`, which is a different type.

Once you fix that, you'll find that you can't call the function because it is private; likewise, you can't access `DE::U` since that's also private. (**UPDATE**: this refers to the question as originally posted, before `public` access specifiers were added.)